# Statistics: Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

$P(A│B)=\frac25$  ,$P(B)=\frac14$, $P(A)=\frac13$. Find

1. $P(A\land B)$
2. $P(B|A)$

Here is what I did:

### Part 1.

$$P(A\land B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)\\
= \frac13\cdot\frac14=\frac{1}{12}$$

### Part 2.

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(B\land A)}{P(A)} = \frac{\frac1{12}}{\frac13}=\frac14$$

I'm not too sure if my answers are right and I will like them checked over. Thanks

Comment: You assume $A$ and $B$ are independent in your answer to (a) but you cannot assume that.

Comment: You recieved several answers to your question. Is any of them what you want? If so, accept it-this is how this site works!

Answer (score 4):

For part (a), you made a mistake. It is *not* true that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$. This is only true if $A$ and $B$ are *independent*.

To solve the task, here is a **hint**:

> What is the definition of $P(A|B)$?

For part (b), your solution is OK, but the result is wrong because you calculated $P(A\land B)$ wrong in the first step.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the definition of conditional probability $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

1. $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) = \frac25 \cdot \frac14 = \frac{1}{10}$
2. $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{\frac{1}{10}}{\frac13} = \frac{3}{10}$

Comment: For part b, since it is going to be over P(B), shouldn't it be 1/10 divide 1/4 and not 1/10 divide 1/3 ?

Comment: @Ken In the OP, one sees $P(B|A)$, which means "the probability of event $B$ given that event $A$ will happen", so using the definition of conditional probability, $P(A) = \frac13$ should be the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ unless $A$ and $B$ are independent which they aren't.  Instead use $p(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$.  You are given two of those values so you just need to plug those in to solve for the one you don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the definition of $P(A \cap B)$:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B) \times P(B) = P(B|A) \times P(A)$

Since you know $P(A|B), P(B)$ and $P(A)$ you can easily deduce the rest.

As Gregory mentioned, you are incorrectly assuming that A and B are independent i.e. $P(A|B) = P(A)$ and $P(B|A) = P(B)$.